# Can we query google big query public datasets using Simba JDBC driver?

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, simba

I want to test connectivity and queries using Google Big query for google query pubic projects/datasets like "bigquery-public-data" or any other public datasets using Simba JDBC driver.

I tried different authentication mentioned in Simba driver documentation but couldn't find any option in [their documentation](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/authenticating/serviceaccount.htm).

I know that if I create my own project and dataset (For which I need enable billing in that project) then I can use service account authentication method using Simba JDBC driver, but before I enable billing for my project I wanted to try out querying some public datasets, but for public datasets I couldn't find a way to query using JDBC driver(using some 3rd party open source tools like SQL-Workbench or SQuirreL SQL client).

Can someone please let me know if it is possible or not?

Comment: Querying public datasets using BigQuery UI works fine but wanted to check if I can query public projects/datasets using Simba JDBC driver or not.

Comment: I set up service account and empty project without billing option and can query public datasets from withing DataGrip UI. I user Simba jdbc driver 1.2.1.1001

Answer (score 0):

If it worked in the UI it should also work via any other interface - just make sure you use your own project for billing and only refer to the public data project in the query.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for quick response, but from Google Big Query UI I can access public project data even without setting up billing for any of my project.

Comment: The first TB per month is free - I guess that's why it is working. You still need your own project - I don't think you have jobs create permissions for their projects - that'd be an interesting choice of them. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/jobs-overview

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and you need at least a project set, otherwise you cannot access to the BigQuery UI.

You should follow the instructions [here](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/using/intro.htm) to install and use the Simba JDBC driver. You can integrate it in the [Java client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

If you are getting a specific error, please edit the post and update the information.

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC driver has a specific [`AdditionalProjects`](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/v2/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/options/ui/additionalprojects.htm) parameter for that where you would add `bigquery-public-data`.

There is no such option on the JDBC driver. The closest would be [`ProjectId`](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/options/projectid.htm) but not sure it would work as this is to set the billing project - and you cannot charge the "public dataset project".

You might just to away with it by fully qualifying the tables you want to query, enclosed by backtick characters e.g. `` `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.us_msa_area` ``.

Answer (score 0):

***Data*** and ***compute*** should be looked separately.

***Data*** : Is offered from the public dataset.

***Compute***: When you run queries, it uses the compute slots to process the data. You need to atleast have a trial account to use the free tier compute slots for running queries.

**Supplying project/data set info for Simba ODBC driver**

Use User or service authentication as necessary.
At the bottom, choose the project in which you billing account.

1. Catalog(Project) -> Provide your billing account project name

Eg.

> mybigquery

2. Dataset ->  Qualify it with the public dataset.

Eg.

> bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain

Test the connection and click "OK". Thats it.